# Which file does includegraphics select if there are multiple files with different extensions?

Tags: includegraphics

We usually write something like

```
\includegraphics{image}
```

instead of:

```
\includegraphics{image.png}
```

That is, `\includegraphics` does not usually require a file extension such as `.png` `.pdf` `.jpg`, etc... That is,

Suppose that I have all of the following files in the same directory. Which file will `\includegraphics` embed?

```
my_pic.jpg
my_pic.psd
my_pic.png
my_pic.pdf
my_pic.jpeg
my_pic.gif
```

Document:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htpb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{my_pic}
   \caption{Sunshine and Rainbows}
  \Description{summertime}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: Environment figure undefined`

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the engine. With pdftex the current list (which you can find in pdftex.def) is:

```
\def\Gin@extensions{%
  .pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,%
  .PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPEG,.JBIG2,.JB2%
}
```

That means that e.g. pdf will be prefered, then png etc.

Comment: Very useful. It could be in `graphicx` documentation.

Comment: I always wondered: what's the point of this? Why doesn't it simply accept the full name of the file?

Comment: @Bakuriu it does accept the full name of the file. `example-image.pdf` works fine.

Comment: @Sigur the user documentation tells you how to set the list `texdoc graphics` section 4.5 `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`  the default is driver specific and initially there were dozens of different drivers they are not documented in the core documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As documented in the graphics guide (section 4.5), this is user settable.

If you have

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png}
```

in your document then it will just try `.pdf` then `.png` in that order, and ignore the rest.

The default value as shown in Ulrike's answer is set in the driver file for the option you are using. (Using a lower level `\def` syntax rather than `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` because the driver files might be loaded by the `color` package, before `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions`  is defined.)